# Cropping two layers of polygons using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am new in QGIS and I would like to know if it's possible to crop two layers of polygons.

I have a layer A with some polygons and a layer B with some others.

I want that if the distance of one polygon of the layer A is shorter than 5m to a polygon of the layer B, it moves the border of the layer A to 5m.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Could you please add a sketch of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I think I understand your question from the description. I posted an answer below. If I misunderstood, please update your question with a sketch or drawing as Erik suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use the `Buffer` tool to make a 5 m buffer around layer B.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Use the `Difference` tool to subtract the buffer layer from  layer A.**

[image]

[image]